# Upgrade MacBook Pro Bluetooth

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

Is there a way to upgrade my MacBook Pro late 2011 MacBook Pro 13" Bluetooth to Bluetooth 4.0 without using a usb extension? As I only have one working USB port.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a way to do that.

Aside of software/firmware from Apple, there is the hardware issue as well.

Comment: There is software/firmware??

Comment: As Buscar said, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: from Apple for your model ?

Comment: There is no way to upgrade the hardware?

Comment: Not without changing the logic board.

Answer (score 1):

QuickerTek makes a card that replaces the Apple WiFi/Bluetooth card. A bit pricey at $149:
http://www.quickertek.com/products/Ucard.html
This works in 2011-2012 13" and 15" MacBook Pros (non-retina). The version for 2011-2012 MacBook Pros (non-Retina) uses Apple's driver.

Also have versions for:

- 2010 15" MacBook Pro - uses a firmware patch
- 2009-2010 13" and 15" MacBook Pro, and 2009-2011 17" MacBook Pro - uses a firmware patch and have to disable original Bluetooth card

QuickerTek also makes cards for MacBook Airs and Retina MacBook Pros.